# Imagemagick command line in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I've got the following two commands for imagemagick in the command line:

```
convert in.png container-mask.png +matte -compose CopyOpacity -composite  out.png
composite container.png  out.png -compose multiply final.png
```

Those two commands include 3 files:

- **in.png**: the file that should be masked
- **container-mask.png**: the back/white mask of the areas of *container.png* where *in.png* should be visible
- **container.png** image that includes the container for *in.png*, the one that has been masked in black/white with *container-mask.png*

Now the question is how to transpose this commands into PHP calls. I've played around quite a bit, but I can't make sense of the API at http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Thanks and Bests,
Charly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer. Well, that was not too complicated after all:

```
$original = new Imagick("in.png");
$mask = new Imagick("container-mask.png");
$container = new Imagick("container.png");

$mask->setImageMatte(0);
$original->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
$container->compositeImage($original, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0,0);
$container->setImageFormat( "png" );
echo $container;
```

Comment: For any activity you can perform on command line but no library within PHP, if any normal user (not super user or administrator or root, etc.) can perform that task, you may use `exec()`. But need to provide absolute paths for the tools.

Comment: Do NOT use double quotations as string qualifier unless you're using variable interpolation. Use single quotations instead.

Comment: @AmilWaduwawara but can I get the Output of any executed command from Exec()?